# Salvar associações cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Estou tentando salvar dados associados em Cakephp 3, no banco de dados tenho duas tabelas `tabela entidades(id, nome_principal)` e `enderecos(id, entidade_id, cidade)`

Em `EntidadesTable` eu realizei a associação:

```
$this->hasMany('Enderecos', array(
    'className' => 'Enderecos',
    'foreignkey' => 'entidade_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
));
```

No *controller* `Entidades` eu salvo com os seguintes dados:

```
$entidade = $this->Entidades->newEntity();

if ($this->request->is('post')){
    $entidade = $this->Entidades->patchEntity($entidade, $this->request->getData());
    if ($this->Entidades->save($entidade)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('Entidade cadastrada com sucesso!'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'consultar']);
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Ops, algo deu errado, verifique se os campos foram preenchidos corretamente!'));
    }
}

$this->set(compact('entidade'));
```

E na view, meu form está assim:

```
<p><strong>Nome<strong><p>  
<p><input type="text" id="nome_principal" name="nome_principal" placeholder="Nome" class="form-control input-md"></p>
<p><strong>Cidade<strong><p>  
<p><input type="text" id="cidade" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" class="form-control input-md"></p>
```

Os dados da entidade salva normalmente no banco de dados, mas o `entidade_id` e `cidade` da tabela `enderecos` não salvam, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Por favor não esqueça de mencionar a versão exata do CakePHP (última linha em vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt ou lib/Cake/VERSION.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editei o patchEntity passando a chave `associated` que informa o model associado que será salvo:

```
$entidade = $this->Entidades->patchEntity($entidade, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['Enderecos']]);
```

Aqui eu criei seus inputs utilizando o FormHelper seguindo o padrão de dados associados:

```
echo $this->Form->control('nome_principal', ['id' => 'nome_principal', 'class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Nome', 'label' => 'Nome']);
// Enderecos controls (hasMany)
echo $this->Form->control('enderecos.0.cidade', ['id' => 'cidade', 'class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Cidade', 'label' => 'Cidade']);
```

Veja [Saving HasMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations) e [Converting Request Data into Entities](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data) para mais detalhes.

Comment: Fecho o balão Rayann, obrigado pela ajuda!